# Ceiling light, two black wires

Tags: lighting

I've got this ceiling light with two black wires. From what I understand I'm to put black with black and white with white. How do I hook up this lamp with this outlet?...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Lights don't really care.

Main thing is that one wire(the hot one should go to the centre post of the light to protect you).

If you have a multi-meter can find which wire goes to the centre post and which to the threaded section.

The threaded section should connected to the white wire in the box.

If the wires are mixed up it will work well.  The only thing is to keep your fingers from the threaded section since it causes an oops(bad hurt).

Comment: Usually they'll wire the bulbs together inside the fixture, and then run one wire up to make it simple to install. In this case, there are probably two bulbs (or sets of bulbs) and they're meant to be spliced on the same nut (or wago) as the line wire in your box. It could in theory be used to run two switches and control the lights separately, but you probably don't want that.

Answer (score -1):

It's not likely that fixture is UL-approved, and so illegal to install anywhere a normal electrical code is in effect. So get whoever codged that fixture together to mark the wires appropriately. And if you continue on with the idea that "black to black, and white to white" is a suitable philosophy for working with house wiring, then you have many big sparks, loud bangs, and small disasters in store for you.

Comment: What are you gonna do, call the cops?